# Using grep to filter out words from a stopwords file

Tags: linux, grep, stop-words

I want to use grep together with a stopwords-file to filter out common english words from another file. The file "somefile" contains one word per line.

```
cat somefile | grep -v -f stopwords
```

The problem with this approach is: It checks whether a word in stopwords occurs in somefile, but I want the opposite, i.e. check if a word in somefile occurs in stopwords.

How to do this?

**Example**

somefile contains the following:

```
hello
o
orange
```

stopwords contains the following:

```
o
```

I want to filter out only the word "o" from somefile, not hello and orange.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I thought about it some more, and found a solution...

use the `-w` switch of `grep` to match whole words:

```
grep -v -w -f stopwords somefile
```

Comment: or `grep -v -w -f stopwords somefile` avoiding the `cat` command

Comment: I changed the answer based on your cleanup suggestion @Matthias

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have stopwords file /tmp/words:

```
in
the
```

you can create from it sed program by:

```
sed 's|^|s/\\<|; s|$|\\>/[CENSORED]/g;|' /tmp/words > /tmp/words.sed
```

this way you will get /tmp/words.sed:

```
s/\<in\>/[CENSORED]/g;
s/\<the\>/[CENSORED]/g;
```

and then use it to censor any text file:

```
sed -e -f /tmp/words.sed /input/file/to/filter.txt > /censored/output.txt
```

The `-e` is needed for sed to understand extended regexp needed for  recognition.
Of course you can change `[censored]` to any other string or empty string if you wish.

This solution will handle many words in line as well as one word per line files.